# FileNotFoundException open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted) during saving image file to internal storage on android

Tags: java, android, file-io

I faced this problem when I tried to save the image to internal storage on android.

```
public static String setImage(Bitmap image) {
    if (image != null) {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Caramel");
        dir.mkdir();
        String fileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(dir, fileName);
        try {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            return fileName;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (outputStream != null) {
                    outputStream.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

All goes nice and well, and I can see my Bitmap image in debug mode, but all the same, i get the next error:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Caramel/1587724428205.jpg: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
    W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:495)
    W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:235)
    W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:186)
    W/System.err:     at com.example.caramel.Position.setImage(Position.java:176)
    W/System.err:     at com.example.caramel.PositionActivity.onActivityResult(PositionActivity.java:129)
    W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8300)
    W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4905)
    W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4953)
    W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
    W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2043)
    W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
    W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7464)
    W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
    W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:955)
    W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
    W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
    W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
    W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:254)
    W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
    W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7360)
    W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:481)
    W/System.err:   ... 17 more
```

It seems, that reason could be in my Manifest.xml file, but i've already set these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

Thanks for your support, guys.

Comment: The reason is that you are on Android Q where that path is unavailable.

Comment: If you are not on Android Q then you did not implement runtime permission.

Comment: I am seeing this error under Android 12.  I can copy an M3U8 playlist file to the public DCIM folder from my APK asset folder in my app. So I can create the file OK. However when I try to append updated MP4 entries to the playlist (which I have created in the DCIM folder) the OS then creates the exception because of the file extension "M3U8" which is not a typical file extension to be found in the DCIM folder. So I believe the OS is policing public folders according to file type/extension.

Answer (score 38):

I got the issue
In android 11 ":" is not allowed in file name.
And when you append date at the end of file name its add ":" at the end.
so just replace all ":" with "." and its working fine.

```
        String fileName = 
              System.currentTimeMillis().toString().replaceAll(":", ".") + ".jpg";
```

Comment: I have a similar issue with the file name "?.txt" in Android 12 API 31. I can store it locally in my app (SFTP Server s0 v1) directory "/data/data/ch.becke.sftp_server__s0_v1/files" but when I store it on the external storage directory "/storage/emulated/0/Download" I get this error "android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)". Other file names are no problem. Do you have evidence which file name characters are allowed in which Android Version?

Answer (score 16):

As a temporary fix you could do: In your `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` file, at

```
<application android:label="APPNAME" android:icon="ICONNAME" ...>
```

add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`, like so:

```
<application android:label="APPNAME" android:icon="ICONNAME" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
```

It will then use the pre-Android 10 way of requesting access to storage, so you can still save your file as you could earlier.

*But caution: After you update your app to target Android 11 (API level 30), the system ignores the requestLegacyExternalStorage attribute when your app is running on Android 11 devices, so your app must be ready to support scoped storage and to migrate app data for users on those devices. See https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#opt-out-scoped-storage for more info*

Comment: already set android:requestLegacyExternalStorage=true

Answer (score 9):

The permission system in android is very strict, you must take this into account when writing to internal memory
Try something like this:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   Button save;
   Bitmap bitmap;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mario);
      bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
      save = findViewById(R.id.save);
      save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
            File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            File file = new File(directory, "UniqueFileName" + ".jpg");
            if (!file.exists()) {
               Log.d("path", file.toString());
               FileOutputStream fos = null;
               try {
                  fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                  fos.flush();
                  fos.close();
               } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }
            }
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In android 11 you can use this pattern

```java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1) {
    mPath= getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) + "/" + now + ".jpeg";
}
else
{
    mPath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpeg";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Add the following attribute in your app's Manifest.xml file inside the application tag:

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Finally, it will look like this:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
...
</application>
```

Comment: already set android:requestLegacyExternalStorage=true

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest to change it to

```
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(mContext);
    String fullPath =cw.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).toString();
    File directory = cw.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
```

check it here https://www.programmersought.com/article/50766505696/

Answer (score 5):

Apparently if you're trying to save to the internal storage for Android 11, you can NOT save in /storage/emulated/0. Only in public folders like Download, Document, etc. This was the case for me, at least.

Answer (score 2):

you need to grant permission on the Android emulator:

- touch your app in Android Emulator 2 seconds,
- go to app info.

[image: app info on Android Emulator]

- go to permissions.
- select Files and media
- Allow management files.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me: **MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**

in file **pubspec.yaml**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.13.4
  permission_handler: ^9.0.2
  flutter_downloader: ^1.5.2
  path_provider: ^2.0.9
  external_path: ^1.0.1
```

in file **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<application
        android:label="ejemplo_test"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
<provider
           android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvider"
           android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter_downloader.provider"
           android:exported="false"
           android:grantUriPermissions="true">
           <meta-data
               android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
               android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
       </provider>
```

in file **main.dart**

```
    void main() async{
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await FlutterDownloader.initialize(
          debug: true
      );
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }
    
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      String localPath = "";
      int progress = 0;
      ReceivePort _port = ReceivePort();
    
    @override
      void initState(){
        super.initState();
        initPlatformState();
        IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(_port.sendPort, 'downloader_send_port');
        _port.listen((dynamic data) {
          String id = data[0];
          DownloadTaskStatus status = data[1];
          int progress = data[2];
          setState((){ });
        });
        FlutterDownloader.registerCallback(downloadCallback);
        _requestPermissions();
      }

@override
  void dispose() {
    IsolateNameServer.removePortNameMapping('downloader_send_port');
    super.dispose();
  }

  static void downloadCallback(String id, DownloadTaskStatus status, int progress) {
    final SendPort? send = IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName('downloader_send_port');
    send?.send([id, status, progress]);
  }

Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    final path = await ExternalPath.getExternalStorageDirectories();
    setState(() {
      localPath = path[0].toString()+"/Android/media/NameAPP";
    });
    log("path: ${localPath}");
    final savedDir = Directory(localPath);
    bool hasExisted = await savedDir.exists();
    if (!hasExisted) {
      savedDir.create(recursive: true);
    }
  }

SaveImages(String url,String name) async{
    log("url: ${url}");
    log("name: ${name}");
    final id = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
      url:"${url}",
      savedDir: localPath,
      fileName: name.toString(),
      showNotification: true,
      openFileFromNotification: true,
    );
  }

Future<void> _requestPermissions() async {
    Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
      Permission.storage,
      Permission.manageExternalStorage
    ].request();
    log("statuses: ${statuses}");
    if (statuses == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      //createFolder("TiendaOnline");
      MensajeToast("Permission granted.",Colors.green);
    } else if (statuses == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      MensajeToast("Denied. Show a dialog with a reason and again ask for the permission.",Colors.red);
    } else if (statuses == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
      MensajeToast("Take the user to the settings page.",Colors.red);
    }
  }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save photos in DCIM or create a directory in it in Android 11, which is a good pattern. I'm having the same problem, however after I do this, everything works fine.

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1) {
    Yourpath= getActivity().getExternalFilesDir
    (Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) + "/" + nameoffile + ".jpeg";
      }
    else
       {
     
       Yourpath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
      .toString() + "/" + nameoffile + ".jpeg";
       }
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Android 11 means SDK_INT 30 bro, I think you're doing something wrong here

Answer (score 1):

Starting with SDK version 30, you can NOT extend `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`. Instead modify you ImageLoader library a little. I see you have to modify you file path: `File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Caramel");` into something like `File dir = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Caramel");`. This should do a trick.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, file name causes the problem. When my file name was from date time and the format like that : 13-02-2024 23:22:43,  so the problem `open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)` arise, but when I give the name such as `13-02-2024-23-22-43` and the problem gone.

Answer (score -1):

I simply wrote these lines of code and it started to work

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

Also, add this in "import" part of your code

```
import android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
import android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Answer (score -3):

For me, changing both the `compileSdkVersion` and the `targetSdkVersion` to **30** solved the problem.