# Creating a CSV file in Android 11 Return Error "java.io.FileNotFoundException: EPERM (Operation not permitted)"

Tags: android, csv, android-11

Hello I am trying to create a csv file in my android application. My code works when I try to run it on android 10 below. But I cant seem to find a problem why I cant do it on devices that are Android 11 already.

Here is my Manifest Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
        ...
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
```

Here is my code where I create a folder inside the download folder

```
@NonNull
public static File getStorageDirectory() {
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState() == null) {

        File f = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Download/(Project Name)/");

        if(!f.exists())
            f.mkdirs();
        return f;
    } else {
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Download/(Project Name)/");
        if(!f.exists())
            f.mkdirs();
        return f;
    }
}
```

Here is my code on how I create my csv file

```
File baseDir = Utility.getStorageDirectory();
String fileName = pollutant.getStationName();
String date = Utility.convertDate(new Date().getTime(), "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
File csvFile = new File(baseDir, fileName + "(1hr - "+pollutant.getPollutantName()+")(" + date + ").csv");

FileWriter writer;
if(csvFile.exists() && !csvFile.isDirectory()) {
    writer = new FileWriter(csvFile , true);
} else {
    writer = new FileWriter(csvFile);
}
```

I am already creating a folder in the download folder in android 11 problem is when I am trying to do the create csv part program return a

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ... open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

I am really having a hard time to fix my problem for devices with android 11

Comment: This is  familiar problem, Had you write a code for Permission To Write into the file?

Comment: Long press on your app, click on  ```info`` go to the app permission you will get what I mean

Comment: I have a permission for storage.

Comment: sure , wait a second

Comment: After this should be working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FileNotFoundException open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted) during saving image file to internal storage on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61406818/filenotfoundexception-open-failed-eperm-operation-not-permitted-during-saving)

Comment: `f.mkdirs();` You complain that you cannot create a file. But very probanbly you cannot create that directory and you are unaware. `if(!f.mkdirs()){Toast ( ..could not cresta directory..); return null;}`. The caller should check for null.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"

You have a forbidden character in your file name.

A `:` is not allowed.

Change to `"dd-MM-yyyy HH.mm.ss"` or so.

Comment: I have a similar issue with the file name "?.txt". I can store it locally in my app (SFTP Server s0 v1) directory "/data/data/ch.becke.sftp_server__s0_v1/files" but when I store it on the external storage directory "/storage/emulated/0/Download" I get this error "android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)". Other file names are no problem. Do you have evidence which file name characters are allowed in which Android Version? (Actually Android is based on Linux and on Linux I can have ":" and "?" in my file name without issues ...)

Comment: allowed file name characters

Comment: Do you know an an article/web-site where it is listed/explained which characters are allowed and which ones are not?
BUT this does not explain why using my Android SFTP Server s0 v1 App I can upload and store files containing special characters ":", "?", ... to my app directory "/data/data/ch.becke.sftp_server__s0_v1/files" but not on the external storage directory e.g. "/storage/emulated/0/Download".

Comment: In my last comment i suggested where to google on.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this a permission issue. In Order to Write into files you need to allow it.
Here is example of the code:

```java
public void onPermission() 
{
// Permision can add more at your convinient
    if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) !=
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
         {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            new String[] 
            {
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                    Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE
            },
            0
        );
    }
}
```

Usage :

`onPermission();` at `onStart()` or in the `onAcitivty()`.

Alternatively you can use a library as well ,

Reference : https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter

---

For External Storage:
Add attribute in your app's AndroidManifest.xml file inside the application tag:

`android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

eg.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
...
</application>
```

For More Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61406983/10758321

Comment: I tried to implement this on my onActivity part. It still returns the same error.

Comment: I have updated my answer, Let me know if that helps!

Comment: yes I already have the android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in my manifest file. It is still returning the same error.

Comment: had you clean the Project?

Comment: Yes I have. I really can't figure out what is missing in my project for it to run in Android 11 it works fine in Android 10 below....

Comment: This have to do with the Directory Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61406983/10758321

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar behavior in my “SFTP Server s0 v1” app and the problem respective the allowed characters in file- and directory-names is related to the underlying file system – see [Comparison of file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems) . You can check which file system is mounted to which directory by calling `adb shell mount`. For example creating a file in your application home directory (e.g. `/data/data/ch.becke.sftp_server__s0_v1/files`) is no issue because the `/data` directory is mounted as `ext4` (`/dev/block/dm-5 on /data type ext4 ...`) which allows almost all characters in file names. Whereas the external storage directory (e.g. `/storage/emulated/0` or `/storage/140E-3C1A`) is mounted as `vfat` or `fuse` which only allows a limited set of characters in file names. (in my app I alternatively also support managing files using scoped storage but I personally think this is even worse because it auto replaces all special characters with an underscore character `_`).