# How to take storage permission in Android 13?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, file

**BroadcastReceiver File**

```
class CallReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
private var mediaRecorder : MediaRecorder? = null

override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    val state : String
  if(intent?.action.equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")){
      if(intent?.extras != null){
          state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).toString()
          when(state){
              TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING -> {
                  Log.d("CallRec", "Ringing......")
              }

              TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK -> {
                  startRecording(context)
              }

              TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE ->{
                  stopRecording()
              }
          }
      }
  }
}


private fun startRecording(context: Context?) {
    if(context != null){
        mediaRecorder = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) MediaRecorder(context) else MediaRecorder()
    }

    mediaRecorder?.apply {
        setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION)
        setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB)
        setOutputFile(getRecordingFilePath())
        setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)
    }

    try {
        mediaRecorder?.prepare()
        mediaRecorder?.start()
    }
    catch (e : IOException){
        Log.d("CallError", e.toString())
    }


    Log.d("CallRec", "Call Recording Start......")
}


private fun stopRecording(){
    try {
        mediaRecorder?.stop()
        mediaRecorder?.release()
    }
    catch (e : Exception){
        Log.d("CallError", e.toString())
    }
    mediaRecorder = null
    Log.d("CallRec", "Call Recording Stopped......")
}


private fun getRecordingFilePath(): String {
    val directory = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "TestRecording")
    if(!directory.exists()){
        directory.mkdir()
    }
    val filePath = File(directory, "testing_${System.currentTimeMillis()}" + ".amr")
    return filePath.path
}
```

}
**MainActivity Class**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private var callReceiver = CallReceiver()
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
  
  allowPermission()

    val makeCall: Button = findViewById(R.id.makeCall)
    makeCall.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    if(hasPermission()) {
        val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
        intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")
        this.registerReceiver(callReceiver, intentFilter)
    }
    else{
        allowPermission()
    }
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    this.unregisterReceiver(callReceiver)
}

private fun allowPermission() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
        this, arrayOf(
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
        ), 2
    )
}

private fun hasPermission() : Boolean{
    val phoneStatePermission = Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
    val writeFilePermission = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    val recordAudioPermission = Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
    return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, phoneStatePermission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            &&   ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, writeFilePermission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            &&   ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, recordAudioPermission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

}
```

}

**Manifest File**

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="28"
    />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />





<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.CallRecording"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

**LogCat**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/TestRecording/testing_1694590203887.amr: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I am building a call recording app and I want to store recorded audio file in a custom directory. When I run this app on android 8, it is working perfectly. But for android 13, it is giving EPERM (Operation not permitted) exception. I think the issue is related to permissions.

Comment: Scoped storage is the one you're looking for

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FileNotFoundException open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted) during saving image file to internal storage on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61406818/filenotfoundexception-open-failed-eperm-operation-not-permitted-during-saving)

Comment: You still haven't posted your LogCat; please do soon if you don't want this question closed too.

Comment: Added LogCat; Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Google restricted call recording feature to only system apps. It won't work above Android 8.
[https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9888170]

Comment: For my interview I was given the assignment to make this app. And there are many apps on play store that do the same.

Comment: Please share your code if you can achieve this. I am sure that this is not possible. I worked on this module for a week. I learned that this is not possible in android now. The apps you see in play store wont work. Install and try it. Don't waste your time brother.

Comment: Yeah! you are right. I wasted enough time on this application.

Answer (score 0):

On an Android 13 device you should not request the usual WRITE permission as you have it by default.

But you cannot create your folder "TestRecording" in root of external storage.

Instead create your folder in one of the public directiries that are already there like Download, Documents, DCIM, Pictures, Video..